# Regular Expression Works In One Script and Doesn't In Another

Tags: php, regex

I've stumbled across an interesting bug in PHP. Basically I have a regular expression seen below which works fine in one script (Script A) but fails to work when put into a class and used in a script (Script B).

I have tested this script on PHP 5.3, and 5.2.

**Script A:**
http://iamdb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/testing.php

**Script B:**
Class the regex is used in: http://iamdb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/imdb/search/imdb_search_title.class.php
Script calling it: http://iamdb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/Search_Debug.php

**Regular Expression:**

```
"#<br> aka <em>\"([^\"]*)\"</em>(?: -?,? ([^ ]*) (?:<em>\(([^\)]*)\)</em>)*)*#i"
```

Thanks.

As requested, here is some example output from Script B...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [INPUT] => <small>(TV series)</small>    <br>aka <em>"Hammer Time"</em> - USA <em>(working title)</em>
)
```

The numbered keys are from the preg_match_all call and the INPUT key is added afterwards to show the input string.

Comment: What do you mean, fails to work?  What's the input and output of the call to the class member?

Comment: As a side note, it's a bad idea to try to parse XML/HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: You offered many compelling alternatives.

Comment: I don't think the name-calling is really appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the debugger, the *subject* of the `preg_replace_all`s don't match between the class and the `test.php` case.

From the test case:

```
<small>(TV series)</small>    <br> aka <em>"Sledge Hammer: The Early Years"</em> - USA <em>(second season title)</em>
```

The actual *subject* when called from the class:

```
<small>(TV series)</small>    <br>aka <em>"Hammer Time"</em> - USA <em>(working title)</em>
```

There's no space between the `<br>` and the `aka`. Take that space out of the regex and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the regex or embedding it in a class.  You're convincing yourself that your test situations are equivalent when they're not.  In the immediate case, the string you're sending the class version,

```
<small>(TV series)</small>    <br>aka <em>"Hammer Time"</em> - USA <em>(working title)</em>
```

isn't matched by the regex because the regex requires exactly one space between the `<br>` and the `aka`.  This revision of it works:

```
const REGEX_AKA = "#<br>\s*aka <em>\"([^\"]*)\"</em>(?: (?:-?)(?:,?) ([^ ]*) (?:<em>\(([^\)]*)\)</em>)*)*#i";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match against an actual search-result page on IMDB, like [this one](http://www.imdb.com/find?s=tt&q=hammer)?  On that page, the `"<br>"` and the `"aka"` are always separated by an entity reference for a non-breaking space:

```
<br>&#160;aka <em>
```

I don't know if it's always that way; you might want allow for multiple kinds and representations of whitepsace, like this:

```
<br>(?:&(?:#(?:160|xA0)|nbsp);|\xA0|\s)*+aka
```

i.e., zero or more of: an entity reference for an NBSP (decimal, hexadecimal or named); a *real* NBSP; or a standard whitespace character.

Comment: Yeah, I decode the HTML entities before running through my regular expressions.